# How to dynamically generate oracle query to get data as per selected time interval

Tags: oracle

I have table containing columns  id, Datum, Value
Datum is of date type.
In this table I have values for every 15 minutes.

Now I'm generating report in which 
User select time interval like 15 minutes 30 minutes 1 hour 1 day
How to dynamically generate oracle query to get data as per selected time interval.

Comment: Pleade provide an example query foe one of these intervals.

Comment: How do you get user input? UI or some database tool?

Comment: I'm using C# Windows application and interval is selected from combobox

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit.                              
 Query to select data if user selects 30 minutes interval.                                          
 Select id, to_char(datum, 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS')Date_Time,value FROM MY_TABLE  where to_char(datum,'Mi') In('00','30')

Comment: If it's a combo-box, how will you restrict the user from entering any garbage interval?

Comment: By changing dropdownstyle properly to list user can select from list and can't type in combobox

Comment: If you have only 4 distinct values then a `IF .. THEN ELSIF ..` or [CASE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm) expression should be appropriate. Build the statement dynamically seems to be an overkill for me if you have just 4 items.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`NUMTODSINTERVAL` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions103.htm) to specify an interval. For example, if you want to get everything from up to 15 minutes ago:

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  DATUM >= SYSDATE - NUMTODSINTERVAL( 15, 'MINUTE' )
```

or, if you want to limit it to not include future values:

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  DATUM BETWEEN SYSDATE - NUMTODSINTERVAL( 15, 'MINUTE' )
                 AND SYSDATE
```

You can change it to take the amount and units of the interval as bind parameters, which you can pass into your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  DATUM >= SYSDATE - NUMTODSINTERVAL( :amount, :units )
```

Where:

- `:amount` is a number; and
- `:units` is one of the strings: `SECOND`, `MINUTE`, `HOUR` or `DAY`

Comment: I don't think that is what has been asked for. I assume Rajendra is more looking for `GROUP BY TRUNC(DATUM, 'HH')`, `GROUP BY TRUNC(DATUM)`, etc. clauses. Let's wait for further information.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit "I did not test it but...." perhaps you ought to test it before making statements like that as it does work as `NUMTODSINTERVAL` is a function that takes two variables and the second argument can be any of the strings: `SECOND`, `MINUTE`, `HOUR` or `DAY` which can be passed in as either a text literal or as a variable containing one of those string values.